# How to make a DOORS boolean attribute/column "False" if another attribute/column is not empty with DXL?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

I have 2 attributes/columns. "A" and "B". A is as string of text. B is a boolean that can be True or False (when you edit it in DOORS, it's a drop down with 2 options T/F).

I want to use DXL to make B False if A is not empty.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm very new and unsure the syntax:

```
Object o
for o in current Module do{
 if((o."A") == null)
 {
  o."B" = "False"
 }
}
```

What I'm doing is I go into edit-mode on the DOORS module, click Edit -> Attributes -> "B" -> Edit... -> check DXL attribute -> Browse... -> New, *write the code* -> Ok, close all windows, Tools -> Refresh DXL Attributes. Correct?

When I Refresh, nothing happens, also when I clicked "check" after writing the code, there was no errors. Also when I go back the Edit -> Attributes and look back at the DXL for "B", I don't see my script there...

Comment: Attribute DXL is calculated for each row separately automatically. The object to be calculated "at this very moment" is given to you in the predefined variable "obj".  This is the reason why you never use loops "for o in module" in DXL Attributes or in DXL Layout columns.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Mike I went ahead and removed the for-loop but it still doesn't work. The result of the code in the answer below makes everything in "B" True. I wonder if this has to do with the data in "A" not being seen as blank/null for whatever reason (when I click into some of the blank "A" cells it really is completely blank as far as I can see). Or if we're using the if statement syntax if((obj."A") == null) incorrectly in some way?

Comment: --> obj."A" <-- is an attribute reference and is never null. If you want to check the content of the attribute against the null string, cast the attribute reference to a string by concatenating it with the null string. I.e. use:  --> if (obj."A" "" == null)  <--  or  --> if (obj."A" "" == "")  <--

Comment: That worked! Thanks @Mike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dxl code

//Go to Edit -> Attributes, select 'B' attribute; select Edit and check the checkbox 'DXL attribute', click the 'Browse' button and paste the following code

//Press F5 to refresh DXL attributes

//Or 'Tool -> Refresh DXL attributes' to refresh DXL attributes

```
 if((obj."A") == null)
 {
  obj.attrDXLName = "False"
 }
 else
 {
   obj.attrDXLName = "True" 
 }
```

Follow the below steps to see or edit the dxl code

1. Select the DXL attribute
2. Click Edit
3. Check the DXL Attribute box
4. Click Browse
5. Click Current

Comment: Your code (placed within my for-loop) worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Actually I'm facing an issue. The code makes everything false, but does not leave anything true.

I made a for-loop to make all the requirements true. Then after I put your code where the null one's should be made false. But instead it makes ALL of "B" false...

Comment: @bijan Sanchez I edited code. Pls check now

Comment: @bijan Sanchez Use code as it is. Don't use for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ashok I went ahead and removed the for-loop but it still doesn't work. The result of your code makes everything in "B" True. I wonder if this has to do with the data in "A" not being seen as blank/null for whatever reason (when I click into some of the blank "A" cells it really is completely blank as far as I can see). Or if we're using the if statement syntax if((obj."A") == null) incorrectly in some way?